# Как установить Gentoo с нужным ядром?

Tags: linux

Ни разу не ставил Gentoo прочел только немного хэндбук, но пока не нашел Как же установить Gentoo с ядром меньше 3 версии. Желательно между 2.6.34 и 2.6.39

Answer (score 1):

Взять более старый срез генту, не? Один фиг потом будете обновляться до нового ядра, рано или поздно.

Comment: Нет не буду обновлять. мне как раз нужно только ядро 2.6а минимал сд я только за 2012 нашел.

Comment: Ну хорошо.Если есть увереность что будете сидеть на одном и том же ядре и версиях прог и системных утилит-берите хэнбук,качайте торренты начиная с 2006.1 http://torrents.gentoo.org/?category=2006.1.На данный момент это древнейшее что можно достать и поставить http://torrents.gentoo.org/torrents/livecd-i686-installer-2006.1.torrent http://torrents.gentoo.org/torrents/livedvd-i686-installer-2006.1.torrent (CD и DVD версии лайв системы.Архитектура x86)

Comment: И прочая древность.Наткнулся случайно.Гента ниже версии 2006 http://linux.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/pub/linux/distributions/gentoo/releases/historical/x86/

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ">=sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-3" >> /etc/portage/package.maskemerge gentoo-sources
```

Вроде должно работать. Или

```
echo ">sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-2.6.39" >> /etc/portage/package.mask
```

Еесли хочешь именно это ядро. Вобщем делай как хочешь, эта команда запрещает устанавливать определенные версии пакета :) в данном случае нельзя ставить версии больше 2.6.39, а если такой нет, portage поставит самую новую из разрешенных.

Comment: этот способ уже пробовал, именно что версии ниже 3 нет на сервере вот и качает последнюю. еще варианты

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Только если ванильное ядро ставить:

```
emerge sys-kernel/vanilla-sources:2.6.38.8
```